# MySQL Insert Statement Queue

Tags: php, mysql, database, logging, transactions

We are building an ajax application in which a users input is submitted for processing to a php script. We are currently writing every request to a log file for tracking. I would like to move this tracking into a database table but I do not want to run a insert statement after request. What I would like to do is set up a 'queue' of transactions (inserts and updates) that need to be processed on the MySQL database. I would then set up a cron job or process to check and process the transactions in the queue. Is there something out there that we could build upon or do we have to just write to plain ol' text log files and process them?

Comment: @Justin welcome to SO. I edited in "queue" as I'm pretty sure that's what you meant. If it wasn't, feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) - it'll queue the requests and insert them as and when the database is ready for them, so you don't overload your DB server.

> Gearman provides a generic application
>   framework to farm out work to other
>   machines or processes that are better
>   suited to do the work. It allows you
>   to do work in parallel, to load
>   balance processing, and to call
>   functions between languages. It can be
>   used in a variety of applications,
>   from high-availability web sites to
>   the transport of database replication
>   events. In other words, it is the
>   nervous system for how distributed
>   processing communicates. A few strong
>   points about Gearman:

There's a recent (and quality) post about using databases for logging [here](http://brian.moonspot.net/logging-with-mysql), which (summarised) says:

- Use MyISAM with concurrent inserts
- Rotate tables daily and use UNION to query
- Use delayed inserts with MySQL or a job processing agent like Gearman (although MySQL has a limit on the number of these it will queue before silently dropping them!)

HighScalability [write up on Gearman](http://highscalability.com/product-gearman-open-source-message-queuing-system).

If you really want to avoid this, you could write the raw SQL statements to a file and process them with this cronjob:

```
mysql loggingDB logTable < fullLog.sql && > fullLog.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can do some of the work for you:

INSERT DELAYED

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html

"The DELAYED option for the INSERT statement is a MySQL extension to standard SQL that is very useful if you have clients that cannot or need not wait for the INSERT to complete. This is a common situation when you use MySQL for logging..."

Unfortunately the "DELAYED" variation is only available on INSERT, not on UPDATE.

Comment: `DELAYED` inserts and replaces were deprecated in MySQL `5.6`. In MySQL `8.0`, `DELAYED` is not supported. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-delayed.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Zend_Queue](https://web.archive.org/web/20120718072319/http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.queue.html) class is your lost 
here is [an example](https://web.archive.org/web/20140220043332/http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/60) as well.