# Asynchronous logging of server-side activities

Tags: asynchronous, logging

I have a web server that on every request produces a log that should be persistently saved in a DB.

Since the request rate is too high, I can't make DB operations on every request.

I thought to do the following thing:

1. Any request to a web server produces a log.
2. This log is placed somewhere in a place where it can be stored in a fast way (redis?)
3. Another service (a cron job?) periodically flushes the data from that place, removes duplicates (yes, there can be duplicates that don't need to be stored in the DB) and makes a single MySQL query to save the data permanently.

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use a common logging library (e.g. log4j) which will manage safely writing your log statements to the file. However you should note that log verbosity can still impact application performance.

After the file is on disk, you can do whatever you like with it - it would be completely normal to ingest that file into Splunk for further processing and ad-hoc searches/alerting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have better performance on this operation, you should send you'r logs to some kind of queue and with a service reading that queue, send all the logs to the database.
I found some information about queue's in mysql. 
[MySQL Insert Statement Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562233/mysql-insert-statement-queue)
regards.